# How can I allow more than one uploaded file to be removed with dropzone using custom confirm dialogue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, confirm

I'm wanting to override the default way that Dropzone handles confirm dialogues when removing uploaded files and I'm almost there to a certain degree. Here's my code.

```
Dropzone.confirm = function(question, accepted, rejected) {
    showConfirm(question);
    $(document).on('click', '#accept-confirm', function() {
        hideConfirm();
        accepted();
    });
}

showConfirm = function(question) {
    var confirm_dialogue = '<div id="confirm-dialogue"><span class="question">'+question+'</span><button id="deny-confirm" class="button">Cancel</button><button id="accept-confirm" class="button">Yes</button></div>';
    $('body').append(confirm_dialogue).addClass('is-showing-confirm');
}

hideConfirm = function() {  
    $('body').removeClass('is-showing-confirm');
    let dialogue = document.getElementById('confirm-dialogue');
    dialogue.parentNode.removeChild(dialogue);
}
```

I can click my remove button, and my custom confirm is displayed. I can confirm the removal and the thumbnail is removed.

The problem is I can only do this for one image. For any other images I want to remove I just get the following error in my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) before using `.on()` because events which are applied to that button are called multiple times like,

```
Dropzone.confirm = function(question, accepted, rejected) {
    showConfirm(question);
    $(document).off('click', '#accept-confirm').on('click', '#accept-confirm', function() {
        hideConfirm();
        accepted();
    });
}
```

Or you can use it once and place your function outside to the `Dropzone.confirm` like,

```
Dropzone.confirm = function(question, accepted, rejected) {
     showConfirm(question);
}
// now it will be called once only,
$(document).on('click', '#accept-confirm', function() {
    hideConfirm();
    accepted();
});
```

And for removing an element from DOM use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove),

```
hideConfirm = function() {  
    $('body').removeClass('is-showing-confirm');
    $('#confirm-dialogue').remove();
}
```

You can check length of the element(which you want to delete) like,

```
dialogue && dialogue.parentNode.removeChild(dialogue);
```

Comment: The first answer works, adding off before on. I don't fully understand what you mean by the events applied to the button are called multiple times but it does work. The second one fails because the accepted() callback isn't available outside of the Dropzone.confirm. Thank you

Comment: I mean that on first time when your Confirm function calls your  `accept-confirm` click event binds to the DOM, and it will bind it again and again whenever your confirm function calls. So there are multiple click events added on a single element. That's why your `hideConfirm` calls again and again which is causing issue of `removeChild`.